# How to use same IvParameterSpec object in different programs?

Tags: java, security, aes, encryption

I have following code in java for encryption

```
import javax.crypto.*;
import javax.crypto.spec.*;
import java.security.*;


public class AES
{
  public byte[] encrypted;
  public byte[] original;

  public String originalString,ske;

  Cipher cipher;
  SecretKeySpec skeySpec;
  static IvParameterSpec spec;
  byte [] iv;
  /*public static String asHex (byte buf[])
  {
    StringBuffer strbuf = new StringBuffer(buf.length * 2);
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < buf.length; i++) {
    if (((int) buf[i] & 0xff) < 0x10)
    strbuf.append("0");
    strbuf.append(Long.toString((int) buf[i] & 0xff, 16));
  }
  return strbuf.toString();
}*/
  public AES()
  {
        try
        {
            String key ="chetan";
            skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(getMD5(key),"AES"); 
            cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");

        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {ex.printStackTrace();}
  }
   private static byte[] getMD5(String input){
        try{
            byte[] bytesOfMessage = input.getBytes("UTF-8");
            MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
            return md.digest(bytesOfMessage);
        }  catch (Exception e){
             return null;
        }
    }

public String AESencryptalgo(byte[] text)
{
    String newtext="";
    try
    {
               cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, skeySpec);
            AlgorithmParameters param = cipher.getParameters();
            IvParameterSpec ivspec=param.getParameterSpec(IvParameterSpec.class);
            iv=ivspec.getIV();
            spec=new IvParameterSpec(iv);
        //AlgorithmParameters params = cipher.getParameters();
        //iv = params.getParameterSpec(IvParameterSpec.class).getIV();
        encrypted = cipher.doFinal(text);

    }
   catch(Exception e)
   {
       e.printStackTrace();
   }
   finally
   {
      newtext=new String(encrypted);
       //System.out.println("ENCRYPTED "+newtext);
       return newtext;
    }
}
public  String AESdecryptalgo(byte[] text)
{
    try
    {

        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, skeySpec ,spec);
        original = cipher.doFinal(text);   //Exception occurs here
        originalString = new String(original);
        return originalString;

    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally
    {

        return originalString;
    }
}
```

Now the problem is that when I want to use spec variable while encrypting in different program it encrypts successfully but when I decrypt the same data using this spec in another program, it gives following error and stack trace:

```
java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: Parameters missing
        at com.sun.crypto.provider.SunJCE_f.a(DashoA13*..)
        at com.sun.crypto.provider.AESCipher.engineInit(DashoA13*..)
        at javax.crypto.Cipher.a(DashoA13*..)
        at javax.crypto.Cipher.a(DashoA13*..)
        at javax.crypto.Cipher.init(DashoA13*..)
        at javax.crypto.Cipher.init(DashoA13*..)
        at AES.AESdecryptalgo(AES.java:81)
        at DatabaseClass.InstRecord(DatabaseCLass.java:230)
```

Please tell me what am doing wrong??

Comment: I suspect you have a basic misunderstanding of how Java works. Nothing in a Java program remains after the program exits. You must explicitly provide for persisting a information that must be used by another program or even another instance of your program. For IVs the normal and correct way to do this is to prepend the IV to the *cipher*, and have the decryption program grab this IV from the cipher.

Answer (score 1):

Is it the *exact* same machine? Are you certain you're using the *exact* same JVM? Do you have the correct JCE installed? Can you set a breakpoint in the working program and make sure your JCE provider is the com.sun.crypto provider? Perhaps you could try using BouncyCastle provider if all else fails

```
import org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider;
...
static {
 Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());
}
```

http://www.bouncycastle.org/wiki/display/JA1/Provider+Installation

Comment: Installing a different provider won't fix a programming bug.

Comment: I agree Greg, unless it's a bug in the crypto provider. It's always good to leave no stone unturned when chasing ghost issues, more information or a different error message could help you solve the real problem :)